# 2D Arrays in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I am self taught with Apps Script, so generally approach one problem at a time, as it comes up. Arrays are confusing!

I am using an API to get the number of social followers for Facebook, Twitter and Instagram accounts. Here is the code so far. Note I have removed the API call specifics for privacy, I have also used fake profile ID's in the above, for example 1111 = Facebook, 2222 = Twitter, etc...

```
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpointUrl, params);
  var jsonss = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var dataset = jsonss.data;
  Logger.log(dataset);
```

`[{dimensions={customer_profile_id=1111, reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31}, metrics={lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=407919.0}}, {dimensions={reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31, customer_profile_id=2222}, metrics={lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=1037310.0}}, {dimensions={reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31, customer_profile_id=3333}, metrics={lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=806522.0}}]`

then map the array -

```
  var followers = dataset.map(function(ex){return [ex.dimensions,ex.metrics]});
  Logger.log(followers);
```

`[[{reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31, customer_profile_id=1111}, {lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=407919.0}], [{reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31, customer_profile_id=2222}, {lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=1037310.0}], [{customer_profile_id=3333, reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31}, {lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=806522.0}]]`

Now I get stuck, I am not sure how to get 'followers_count' when 'profile_id=1111', can someone please help? I have tried using another map function ( `var followers = dataset.map(function(ex){return [ex.dimensions.map(function(ex2){return [ex2.followers_count]}]});` ) however this doesn't work...

Any suggestions to push me in the right direction is very much appreciated!

Comment: Provide `console.log(response)` instead of `Logger`

Comment: If arrays are confusing then that's a problem you have skipped.  Continuing to skip it will continue to cost you more in future solutions.  The methods of Arrays are key to simplifying you code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Logger.log(followers);` is `[[{reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31, customer_profile_id=1111}, {lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=407919.0}], [{reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31, customer_profile_id=2222}, {lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=1037310.0}], [{customer_profile_id=3333, reporting_period.by(day)=2021-10-31}, {lifetime_snapshot.followers_count=806522.0}]]` and you want to retrieve the value of `lifetime_snapshot.followers_count: 407919` by using `customer_profile_id: 1111`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, your values of `followers` is used.

```js
const profile_id = 1111; // Please set customer_profile_id you want to use.

const res = followers.reduce((ar, [a, b]) => {
  if (a["customer_profile_id"] == profile_id) {
    ar.push(b["lifetime_snapshot.followers_count"]);
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
if (res.length == 0) return;
const followers_count = res[0];
console.log(followers_count);
```

- When this script is used for your values of `followers`, I thought that `407919` is retrieved.
- If the same IDs are existing, you can retrieve them using `console.log(res)`.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: thankyou, this worked. I'm not sure I understand how it works, if you have time I'd love a bit more of an explanation as to how the code works. Thankyou!

Comment: @racker Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `followers.reduce(,,,)`, in this case, `ar` is `[]`, and `a, b` are 1st and 2nd elements of each element in an array `followers`. Using these values, when the value of `customer_profile_id` is the same with `profile_id`, the value of `lifetime_snapshot.followers_count` is retrieved. By this, `407919` is obtained. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.